# how can i test my httppost url by localhost of google application engine project

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I made a project on "google application engine" but my url is giving an error "404 not found".How can I test by locally this url?

Comment: Did you install the app engine sdk? (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en)

Comment: yes i have installed the app engine sdk.

Comment: What have you tried already? What's in your `app.yaml` and main application code?

Comment: So, you run the SDK, press Play to start your app and press the Browse button. What happens?